# Generating sample distributions and medians

Tags: r, histogram, distribution, median, sampling

How to calculate medians in R and create a histogram with a normal distribution mu=16 and sigma=4

Comment: What is the data from which you are taking the samples? Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question. For example, what is the data from which you are drawing the samples?

Comment: actually you don't need to know what is the data, you can generate it with random values. You need to know for sure what type of data you are trying to generate. You should complete your answer with what type of distribution you expect @trash

Answer (score 2):

I think that you probably want a sample with 1000 observations but shrinked to size . For doing that, you'll need a sample() function:

```
set.seed(12)
s1 <- sample(x = 1:1000, size = 10)
s2 <- sample(x = 1:1000, size = 40)
median(s1)
median(s2)
hist(s1)
hist(s2)
```

The second option is to go with rnorm(), a function that generates a random sample from a normal distribution based on the specified parameters.

```
set.seed(12)
s1 = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
s2 = rnorm(1000, mean = 35, sd = 0.1))
median(s1)
median(s2)
hist(s1)
hist(s2)
```

Ps. I set the seed to have reproducible results. You may skip that line.

Note that for the second option we assume a normal(Gaussian) distribution.

[image: common distributions]

Learn more about probability distributions here: 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/common-probability-distributions-the-data-scientists-crib-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

n and u are numbers, not vectors. There must be some more information given, such as which distribution you're sampling from, and the population mean and standard deviation. For example, if you want to generate a sample of 1000 from a normal distribution with a mean 0 and sd 1, you would use

```
sample = rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
```

From there you can plot the histogram and calculate median:

```
median(sample)
hist(sample)
```